# JSON post to rails API missing three object values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

After adding and removing a number of columns on my JobDetail model in rails, a simple post of to my rails API is not persisting the whole object. Three columns stay nil. After first creating the table , three new columns have been added and sit after `datetime`. I cannot populate them with a post request. Three fields after `datetime` DO NOT populate and I don't understand why. I have tried with insomnia `rest client` - same problem.

Why can I seed those columns, but not post data to them. I get a done out object - its missing data.

My table looks like this, followed by a look at the objects persisted. `id` 59 shows a post with insomnia, `id` 57 shows a seeded object:

```
create_table "job_details", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "client"
t.string   "material"
t.float    "size_width"
t.float    "size_height"
t.string   "units"
t.integer  "runs"
t.integer  "prints"
t.float    "per_print"
t.float    "discount"
t.float    "price"
t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
t.float    "margin"
t.integer  "chargeable"
t.float    "chargeable_cost"
end

=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<JobDetail id: 59, client: "Mr gedgeway", 
material: "four point canvas", size_width: 44.0, size_height: 22.0, 
units: "cm", runs: nil, prints: 3, per_print: 44.33, discount: 4.0, 
price: 22.33, created_at: "2017-05-20 16:28:32", updated_at: "2017-05-
20 16:28:32", margin: nil, chargeable: nil, chargeable_cost: nil>, #
<JobDetail id: 57, client: "Mr J. Macdonald", material: "Aldo canvas", 
size_width: 20.0, size_height: 15.0, units: "in", runs: 2, prints: 3, 
per_print: 17.7, discount: 0.05, price: 16.82, created_at: "2017-05-20 
16:27:47", updated_at: "2017-05-20 16:27:47", margin: 1.5, chargeable: 
3, chargeable_cost: 23.5>,
```

Comment: Please update the question the JSON POSt method

Comment: You have a JobDetailsController.  I'd first look at the job_detail_param method to make sure the three additional fields are included in the `#permit` arguments

Comment: share your controller code

Comment: It was exactly there.`job_detail_params` needed to be updated. Thanks @SteveTurczyn .